# Is an $n$-order multiple Taylor series equivalent to $n$ successive one-variable series expansions?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion, perturbation-theory

I am dealing with a complicated function $F= F(\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2, \epsilon_3, \epsilon_4)$ where $\epsilon_i \, , i \in \{1,2,3,4\}$ are small parameters. 
I have noticed that a multiple Taylor expansion leads to a drastically different result then taking 4 times a standard Taylor expansion for a single variable. 
I was wondering whether this is true always, or whether there exist situations where both expansions lead to identical results. 
Your help is highly appreciated and desirable.

Sincerely, Hartmut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taylor series become complex when multiple parameters.

Just suppose that you use the first order : it means that you look for the tangent plane to the curve. Then, with two variables $x,y$ the bilinear model looks like $$F=a+b x+ cy +d xy$$ More parameters make life more difficult, for sure.

For three variables $x,y,z$, it would be
$$F=a+b x+ cy +dz +exy+f xz +g yz + h xy z$$